# Using observer event to get updated customer info

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have an observer event that should get the customer when a customer is updated and write it to a var log

my config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Customerupdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mage_Customerupdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Mage_Customerupdate>
                <class>Mage_Customerupdate_Model</class>
            </Mage_Customerupdate>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Mage_Customerupdate>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mage_Customerupdate_observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                    </Mage_Customerupdate>
                </observers>            
            </customer_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

My module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Customerupdate>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mage_Customerupdate>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My Observer

```
<?php
class Mage_Customerupdate_Model_Observer {
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $telephone = $customer->getTelephone();
        Mage::log("{$name} ({$telephone}) updated", null, 'customerupdate.log');
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt at using the observer and so far nothing is happening. I will most likely need longer more specific answers as to how I get this to produce the customer information. at this point all I am trying to get is the name and phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a typo ... this

```
<class>Mage_Customerupdate_observer</class>
```

... should match to ...

```
<models>
    <Mage_Customerupdate> <!-- alias -->
        <class>Mage_Customerupdate_Model</class>
    </Mage_Customerupdate>
</models>
```

Try to change it to (full class name)

```
<class>Mage_Customerupdate_Model_Observer</class>
```

... or better (alias) ...

```
<class>Mage_Customerupdate/observer</class>
```

---

**Edit:**

config.xml should look like ...

```
            <observers>
                <Mage_Customerupdate>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mage_Customerupdate/observer</class> <!-- changed -->
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                </Mage_Customerupdate>
            </observers>
```

For logging use

```
Mage::log("{$name} ({$telephone}) updated", null, 'customerupdate.log', true);
```

Comment: If i understand correctly change the models class to the /observer?

Comment: @JohnBurgess Yes. This should fix it.

Comment: So If I logged into magento(frontside) and updated my customer information, something would get written in the var/log/customerupdate.log?

Comment: @JohnBurgess It should, but if you haven't enabled logging in config section, nothing happens. You can force logging with an 4th parameter in `Mage::log($msg, $level, $file, -->true<--);` Btw ... clear cache after changing config.xml. (Note: change the model class within events node ... not the model declaration itself)

Comment: you mean Mage_Customerupdate.xml?? I had changed it in the config.xml

Comment: @JohnBurgess updated answer. If its not working please lets chat. :)

Comment: That made it write something. one further question, it didn't print the updated telephone number. am I calling that correctly? can you tell?

Comment: @JohnBurgess I think telephone belongs to customers **adresses** ... you can change logging to `Mage::log($customer->debug(), ...)` to get all available information.

Comment: @JohnBurgess seems you solved it. If so, please upvote too :)

Comment: If I had some further questions about how to call certain information would you be able to help me?

Comment: Of course, please open new question.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212288/i-have-created-an-observer-event-module-but-need-help-finding-all-of-the-inform